# Appending array elements to another array in the same order

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, append

I have two JavaScript arrays, one current and one new. I can append new elements of Strings from the new array into the current array, and ONLY new elements.

For example, if I have two arrays `currentArray = [a,d]` and `newArray = [a,b,c,d,e]`, we can see that elements b,c, and e are different (and thus can be appended to currentArray).

My UI allows me to select only the new elements from the new array to append. But currently, it only appends to the current at the end of the array.

If I were to select element b, I want the current array to be `currentArray = [a,b,d]`, not `currentArray= [a,d,b].`

If I were to select element b, and then c, the current array should be `currentArray= [a,b,c,d]`

How do I implement this logic?

Comment: Is `a2` a base array or something which is constant?

Comment: What have you researched and tried regarding Array manipulation? Also you did not specified if those are strings, numbers or what

Comment: I edited the question to be more clear. a2 is the new array.

Comment: Where's the JavaScript that you tried? We also need a *complete* code example to see how you're doing what you're doing. Also, are the array elements just the single characters a..z?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this logic:

```
var baseArray = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"];

function appendEl(arr, element){

  // Parse through baseArray for every possible element.
    return baseArray.filter(function(el){
    // If element is in arr or is the element itself.
    if(arr.indexOf(el)!=-1 || el==element) return true;
    else return false;

  });

}
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/quqecjk1/)**